# Day displayed in Kotlin instead of variable

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, dayofweek

I am new to kotlin and android studio and i am trying to have the day displayed in a text view. My problme is that only the number 1 to 7 is displayed acording to the current day but not the name of the day what do i have to  change to fix this?

```
val day = Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK)

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)




    fun dayOfWeek() {
        val day = Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK)
        println(
            when (day) {
                1 -> "Sunday"
                2 -> "Monday"
                3 -> "Tuesday"
                4 -> "Wednesday"
                5 -> "Thursday"
                6 -> "Friday"
                7 -> "Saturday"
                else -> "Time has stopped"
            }
        )
    }
    tag = findViewById(R.id.Tag)
    tag.text = day.toString()
```

Comment: Don’t code your own method/function to find the name of the day of the week. Java knows the names already. Use `LocalDate.now(ZoneId.systemDefault()).getDayOfWeek().getDisplayName(TextStyle.FULL, Locale.ENGLISH)` for today’s day. It yielded `Tuesday` as I ran it right now. Also I am using and recommending [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) over the old and poorly designed `Calendar` class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code, `day` is an Int property.

You have created a function called `dayOfWeek()` that you never call so that code never runs.

When you do `tag.text = day.toString()`, it is looking at the `day` property, not the `day` variable inside your function. It is usually a bad idea to name a variable the same thing as some property in the same class because it makes the code confusing to read. But that doesn't matter either way in this case because both of them are Ints.

In your `dayOfWeek()` function, you are using a `when` expression to covert `day` to a String, but you are just printing it. You are not storing it in a variable such that it can be used for anything else, like setting it on a TextView.

You can make your function return a String, and use it that way. I would also move your function outside the `onCreate()` function. It is unusual to create a function inside another function for this kind of task.

```
val day = Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK)

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    tag = findViewById(R.id.Tag)
    tag.text = getDayOfWeekText()
}

fun getDayOfWeekText() {
    return when (day) {
        1 -> "Sunday"
        2 -> "Monday"
        3 -> "Tuesday"
        4 -> "Wednesday"
        5 -> "Thursday"
        6 -> "Friday"
        7 -> "Saturday"
        else -> "Time has stopped"
    }
}
```

Or to do this the easy way, and with proper language support:

```
tag.setText(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("EEEE").format(LocalDate.now()))
```

Comment: thanks a lot for this detailed answer now i understand my fault

Answer (score 2):

## *java.time*

The `java.util` Date-Time API and their formatting API, `SimpleDateFormat` are outdated and error-prone. It is recommended to stop using them completely and switch to the [modern Date-Time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-Date-Time.html)<sup>*</sup>.

**Solution using `java.time`, the modern Date-Time API:** There are a couple of ways to do it as shown below:

```
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.ZoneId;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.time.format.TextStyle;
import java.util.Locale;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // If you want to deal with the system timezone, you can simply use
        // LocalDate.now() instead of LocalDate.now(ZoneId.systemDefault()). In order to
        // deal with a specific timezone, replace ZoneId.systemDefault() with the
        // applicable ZoneId e.g. ZoneId.of("Asia/Kabul")
        LocalDate date = LocalDate.now(ZoneId.systemDefault());

        String dow = date.getDayOfWeek().getDisplayName(TextStyle.FULL, Locale.ENGLISH);
        System.out.println(dow);

        // Alternatively,
        DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("EEEE", Locale.ENGLISH);
        dow = dtf.format(date);
        System.out.println(dow);
    }
}
```

[<kbd>ONLINE DEMO</kbd>](https://ideone.com/ypOnBd)

Learn more about the modern Date-Time API from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.

---

<sup>* If you are working for an Android project and your Android API level is still not compliant with Java-8, check [Java 8+ APIs available through desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table). Note that Android 8.0 Oreo already provides [support for `java.time`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/time/package-summary).</sup>

Comment: I don’t think that it in itself solves the problem asked about, but it is very good advice.

Comment: Thanks, @OleV.V. for the feedback. I believe, this is what the OP needs. Of course, the OP will have to write `tag.setText(date.getDayOfWeek().getDisplayName(TextStyle.FULL, Locale.ENGLISH))` or `tag.setText(dtf.format(date))`.